# Read from Pulsar and load to Postgres with asyncio

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, apache-pulsar, asyncpg

I am trying to read data from pulsar and write to postgres table with asyncio and asyncpg in Python.

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg
import requests
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
        
class Connection:

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    @classmethod
    async def connect_persist_postgresql(cls, data):
        connection = await asyncpg.connect(
            user='postgres,
            password='password_postgres',
            database='postgres',
            host='10.xxx.xxx.xx',
            port=5432
        )

        query = '''INSERT INTO {}.{} (
                                        uid, 
                                        col1, 
                                        col2, 
                                        col3, 
                                        col4
                                        ) 
                   VALUES (
                           $1, 
                           $2, 
                           $3, 
                           $4, 
                           $5, 
                           )'''
        if isinstance(data, list):
            for event in data:
                await connection.execute(
                    query,
                    'schema',
                    'table_test',
                    event['uid'],
                    event['col1'],
                    event['col2'],
                    event['col3'],
                    event['col4'],
                )
        else:
            await connection.execute(
                query,
                'schema',
                'table_test',
                data[0]['uid'],
                data[0]['col1'],
                data[0]['col2'],
                data[0]['col3'],
                data[0]['col4']
            )

        await connection.close()
```

And then I am connected to pulsar as a consumer, getting data and trying to write into postgresql table with next line:
def run_consumer():

```
client = pulsar.Client(
    'pulsar://10.xxx.xx.xx:6650')
consumer = client.subscribe('test-topic-pulsar-postgresql',
                            'test-subs')
while True:
    msg = consumer.receive()
    unpacked_list = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        my_new_string_value = msg.data()
        unpacked_list.append(my_new_string_value)
        loop.run_until_complete(connect_persist_postgresql(unpacked_list))
    except Exception as a:
        print(a)
```

But I am getting an error: `This event loop is already running`

Any hint is welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing that raises alarm bells for me: `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` at class level  that’s executed when your module is imported. **At most** you want to make that an instance attribute (so set it in an `__init__` method).  Your posted code doesn’t make use of it at all so I can’t judge wether this is the cause of the problem you see.

Comment: You do **not** want to use `loop.run_until_complete()` in a `while True:` infinite loop like that. What’s the goal of the loop there? Why not make that your main asyncio task and issue further tasks from there?

Comment: Ah, your code looks like you are using the  [Apache Pulsar Python client](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-python/), which as a completely different project from the [asyncio project with the same name](https://github.com/quantmind/pulsar). The bad news is that that project is not asyncio aware so you’d have to wrap it in a thread and [be very careful about interacting with asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading).